# .install file not working properly

Tags: hooks, database

I am new to Drupal, and I am trying to write a module with an .install file which will create a database table. The table isn't being created (as seen from the error codes when I try to access it. It also doesn't show up in the Schema module listing) and I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone see if they can find the error?

This is the code:

```
function email_form_schema() {  
  $schema['subscription_info'] = array(
    'description' => t('The base table for nodes.'),
    'fields' => array(
      'first' => array(
        'description' => t('The first name'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'last' => array(
        'description' => t('The last name'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'email' => array(
        'description' => t('The email address'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 32,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => ''
      ),
      'phone' => array(
        'description' => t('The phone number.'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 10,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      )
     ),
    'primary key' => array('email'),
  );

  return $schema;
}   

function email_form_install() {
  // Create my tables.
  drupal_install_schema('email_form');
}

function email_form_uninstall() {
  // Drop my tables.
  drupal_uninstall_schema('email_form');
}
```

Here's the error when I try to access it:

> user warning: Table 'drupal620x120318224310.subscription_info' doesn't exist query: INSERT INTO subscription_info (first, last, email, phone) VALUES ('','','','') in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\modules\drupal620x120318224310\sites\all\modules\email_form\email_form.module on line 123.

I was missing the `return $schema;` line (which I modified above), but it still doesn't work. In the schema module it lists the "subscription_info" table as missing. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had a penny for every time I've done this...

You've forgotten to `return $schema` from your `email_form_schema()` function.

You'll need to reinstall the module (not just disable then re-enable) for the changes to take effect.

There's also a problem with the "last" column. It's a "varchar" and you're using the "unsigned" property which isn't compatible with that type.

You also need to provide the "length" property for all of the "varchar" type columns, including "first" and "last".

Comment: Oops. You're right. But now (in the Schema Module) I now have the error: Tables in the [email_form] schema aren't present in the database, and I still can't access the table. What does this mean?

Comment: I remember this happening in Drupal 6, how are you reinstalling the module? If you're not already I'd install the Devel module then visit http://mysite.com/devel/reinstall. If memory serves selecting to reinstall the module at that path a couple of times will stop the errors and install the table correctly

Comment: I have been uninstalling it manually on the module page. I tried it your way and got the following:

Comment: user warning: Unknown table 'subscription_info' query: DROP TABLE subscription_info in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\modules\drupal620x120318224310\includes\database.mysql-common.inc on line 270.
user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `last` VARCHAR unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `email` VARC' at line 2 query:

Comment: CREATE TABLE subscription_info ( `first` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `last` VARCHAR unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `email` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `phone` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (email) ) /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ in C:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\modules\drupal620x120318224310\includes\database.inc on line 551.
Warning - will delete your module tables and variables.

Comment: Are you able to create a table called `subscription_info` in your database with PHPMyadmin or something similar? Then when you reinstall you won't get that error

Comment: That got rid of the unknown table error, but not the sql error...

Comment: Ah, in that case I'd guess it's because you're using the `unsigned` property on a `varchar` type (those two are incompatible at the MySQL level). It's on the `last` column. You'll have to go through the process of creating the table and reinstalling again I would've thought

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2928/discussion-between-user1015214-and-clive)

Comment: @Clive I would add what you reported in your last comment as part of the answer, in that way, who reads your answer doesn't need to read 7 comments to find some relevant, and important information to know.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thought I had, have I missed something?

Comment: @Clive Whoops… Never mind. I mis-read it.